# how to retrieve data from database in edit text box that display simple dropdown items while typing the letters?

Tags: android

Is there some tutorials that retrieve data from database in edit text box that display simple dropdown items while typing the letters?I am developing a translation application where the user will type a word. While typing the letters of the word, the EditText has an ability to suggest the word in a form of dropdown menu to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you implement a class which extends AutoCompleteTextView.
Then you use

```
myACTV.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

where

```
mActivities = new SimpleCursorAdapter(...);
```

Have a search starting at

[SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#q=simplecursoradapter)

Then limit the results to the Training category on the left hand side of the web page.

The Notepad Exercise should get you further.